# why have a compile error in dependent jar but still could run project successfully?

Tags: maven

When look source code of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` in intellij idea I found this error

```
Class 'BasicDataSource' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getParentLogger()' in 'CommonDataSource'
```

[image]

And I use below maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="123456"/>
    </bean>
```

but my project could run successfully. Then I write a test class to mock this error

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

    interface IA{
        String getParentLog();
    }
    class AImpl implements IA{
        public  void doSomething(){
            System.out.println("doSomething");
        }
    }
}
```

but this time I cannot run it and have a compile error

```
Error:(14, 5) java: com.foobar.Foo.AImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLog() in com.foobar.Foo.IA
```

Why is so?

Answer (score 0):

Two things  -

- First, your part related to DataSources contradicts in the usage. I doubt you might have ended up editing the class `BasicDataSource` post downloading the sources or used some other dependency that brings in another implementation of `DataSource` class implemented in the above sample. Please confirm you are not using any other dependency that brings a conflicting class in the classpath.
- Note while using the mentioned dependency `commons-dbcp:1.4` the class `DataSource` is imported from the package `javax.sql` with following syntax :

  ```
  public interface DataSource extends javax.sql.CommonDataSource, 
                                                java.sql.Wrapper { .. }
  ```
- Second part, the class named `AImpl` is not `abstract` in which case it must define the methods of the `interface` it is implementing as -

  ```
  class AImpl implements IA{
      public  void doSomething(){
          System.out.println("doSomething");
      }


      @Override
      String getParentLog() {
          /** Define how getParentLog is implemented in this class */
         return null; // return string here after the above definition
      }
  }
  ```